# Passing data between 2 controller functions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

To put in simple words I want status1 to go to ajaxleadsreport controller

[image]

A bit more complex explanation:

I have 2 view classes called indexreport and ajaxleadsreport. ajaxleadsreport fetches all the data and displays it. Now I have a GET variable that is being passed to indexreport which I want to be able to pass it to ajaxleadsreport to filter the current data according to the GET variable that has been passed.

Controller Class:

```
public function listsreport($slug='')
    {
        $status1 = $this->input->get('status');
        print_r($status1);
        $main['content']=$this->load->view('crm/leads/indexreport',$content,true);
     }
    public function ajaxleadsreport($p='')
    {       
            $output = array( 'html'=>$this->load->view('crm/leads/ajaxleadsreport',$content, true)); 
        echo json_encode($output); 
    }
```

indexreport View Class:

```
<?php
$i=$return=$uriseg;
$post=$this->input->post(); $sess=$this->session->userdata();
$post = $post?$post:$sess;
?>
<div>
...
</div>
$(document).ready(function (){
  getleads();
 });
function getleads(p){ 

    $.ajax({
    type: "post",dataType:"json",async:false,cache:true,
    url: "<?php echo site_url('leads/ajaxleadsreport'); ?>"+( parseInt(p)>0?'/'+p:''),
    data: $('#objlistform').serialize(),
    success: function(e){$('#leadswrap').hide().html(e.html).fadeIn('slow');} 
  }); return false;
}
```

ajaxleadsreport View class:

```
<?php  
$sess=$this->session->userdata(); 
$status1 = $this->input->get('status');
// This is where I'm trying to put my GET value of status for filtering but it gives NULL.
$post = array('fstatus'=> $status,'fpriority'=> $sessn['fpriority']);
$postd = json_encode(array_filter($post));
?>
...
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function sendreq(){
    setpostdatas();cleartable();getleads();
  }
   var slug = '<?php echo $slug?>';
   var postd = '<?php echo $postd; ?>';
    $('#item-list').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "ajax": {
            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>leads/loadLeads",
            data: {slug: slug, postdata: postd},
            type : 'POST',
            "dataSrc": function ( d ) {
                d.myKey = "myValue";
                if(d.recordsTotal == 0 || d.data == null){
                   $("#item-list_info").text("No records found");
                }
                return d.data;
            }
        },
        'columns': [
            {"data": "id", "id": "id"},
            {"data": "lead_status", "lead_status": "lead_status"},
            {"data": "priority", "priority": "priority"},  
        ]
    });
```

As you can see in the code above, I've tried `$status1 = $this->input->get('status');` in ajaxleadsreport View class but the output for that is NULL, since the GET value is passed in my indexreport view class. When I do a `print_r($status1)` in indexreport controller it gives the right output, but NULL in ajaxleadsreport controller.

So basically now I need a way to pass this GET value to ajaxleadsreport controller.

Comment: Don't call one controller from another. If you need to run some common code in both, move that code into a service (or possibly a protected controller method), which both can call. Then if that code need some arguments, add those as function arguments to the service method and pass it from the controller. So, the controller gets the argument value (GET, POST or what ever, can be different in different controllers), just passes it to the service and then gets the result.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay so suppose you have this value in your URL(`http://localhost/leads/listsreport?status=9`). Now you want to be able to access the `status=9` value in your ajaxleadsreport controller. Could you tell me in code way how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flashdata [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=flash#flashdata):

Set your status to flashdata then get it out in ajaxleadsreport like this: (flashdata only exist once on next request)

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('status', $status1);
```

In ajaxleadsreport:

```
$this->session->flashdata('status');
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller class declare the variable:

```php
protected $status1;
public function listsReport() { 
  $this->status1 =  $this->input->get('status');
  // [...]
}
```

Then you can access `$this->status1` from any function that is invoked after.